# Molecules, Targets and Isoforms

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, human-genetics

I have a question. Given a molecule A and two isoforms of a gene X, Y, and the knowledge that A targets X. Can I infere from this anything about whether A targets Y?

As a motivation think about Furosemide (= A) and SLC12A1, SLC12A2. From Drugbank I know that Furosemide targets SLC12A1, and from KEGG I know that Furosemide targets both genes. I wonder whether I can infer the KEGG knowledge already from the Drugbank knowledge...

Best,
Alex :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  What matters is whether the sequence and folding (if you are talking about binding of A to proteins instead of DNA) of each isoform of your gene still results in the binding of A.

I other words, A may bind to X. Y, an isoform of X may not have the same sequence that A likes to bind to. Or, in the case of proteins and A, Y may fold slightly differently, preventing accessibility of A to Y.